# heterogeneous CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my app, I would like the language to be set in french, and the date format too.
But I'd like to read number formats with decimal points (in english format and not french so (french format is with commas))

Is that possible ?
I imagine something like :

```
public App()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("???");
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the `decimal` separator of the culture:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

Comment: You solution was close. CurrencyDecimalSeparator seems to work only for monetary numbers ("currency"). Finally `culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";` works just fine ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
CultureInfo CustomCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
CustomCulture.DateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat; // Change DateTimeFormat to make date always in en-US Culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CustomCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CustomCulture;

////Date Formats
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd MMMM yyyy Hh:mm:ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd MMMM yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern = "d MMMM";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Comment: I was actually looking for the opposite (numbers are to be "en-US", and date are to be kept in "fr-FR"). The solution of Selman22 led me to the right way. Anyway, your code is interesting too for setting default date time formats. Thanks